# init state for FutureBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

i am confused where can i implement the init state condition for future builder. see whats wrong in my code. in flutter documentation is refer initState for Future builder widget.

```
` @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureLoginuser = loginuser();
  }`
```

i am trying to navigate new screen after response data arrives.my complete code is here i am using go_router for navigation.

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  LoginFormState createState() {
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {

  TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _mobileKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _passwordKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  get message => null;

  get messagecode => null;

  get userinfo => null;

  get token => null;

  Future<Loginuser> loginuser(String mobile, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https:random.url/api/login'),
        body: {'mobile': mobile, 'password': password});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Loginuser.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to update');
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _mobileKey,
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: mobileController,
            autofocus: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter Your Mobile Number",
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            key: _passwordKey,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter Your Password",
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                    FutureBuilder<Loginuser>(
                      future: loginuser(mobileController.text.toString(),
                          passwordController.text.toString()),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          print('snapshsot.hasdata');
                          context.go('/Home');
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    );
                  }
                child: const Text('Submit')),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

`

Comment: onPressed is for changing state asynchronously.  FutureBuilder is for creating an appropriate view based on the state of a Future.  This code is really inside out, and would need to be reconstructed from scratch to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `FutureBuilder` wrong it is a **Widget** that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future. Its usually used to build widgets that need input when a certain future is completed.

In your case use this:

```dart
//first make the onPressed function async
    child ElevatedButton(
        child: Container(),
        onPressed: () async {
          // then await the future You want to complete and then use `.then()` 
          //method to implement the code that you want to implement when the future is completed
          await loginuser(mobileController.text.toString(),
                  passwordController.text.toString())
              .then((result) {
            print('future completed');
            context.go('/Home');
            // For errors use onError to show or check the errors.
          }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
            print(error);
          });
        });
```

*And do validate the form for any error with form key validation method.*

the only way to wait for the future to complete and do something is to use the Asynchronous function either directly as I have shown above or by using the try/catch method both will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
LoginUser? loginUser
 @override
  void initState() async{
    super.initState();
    futureLoginuser = await loginuser();
    ... //  Your navigation here
  }`
```

Try to make your build responsive by checking for `loginUser`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    futureLoginuser == null ?
                  CircularProgressIndicator() : <Rest of your widget>
   }
```

Comment: This should be a FutureBuilder.  Checking for null won't be enough.  Also, initState needs to be sync, not async.

Comment: I understand @RandalSchwartz I just gave a quick workable answer. though it's not preffered to have async in init() And about the conditional reasoning he would anyways route. so it doesn't make sense aswell, the code is broken

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to implement is not correct, here is very basic example to do

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  LoginFormState createState() {
    return LoginFormState();
  }
}

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // your other variables

  bool isValidating = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: mobileController,
            autofocus: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter Your Mobile Number",
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "Enter Your Password",
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: isValidating
                ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                : ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          isValidating = !isValidating;
                        });
                        final r = await loginuser(
                            mobileController.text.toString(),
                            passwordController.text.toString());
                        if (r != null) {
                          // save user state locally, using hive or what alternative you want
                          context.go('/Home');
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Failed'),
                          ));
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          isValidating = !isValidating;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Submit')),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  Future<Loginuser?> loginuser(String mobile, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https:random.url/api/login'),
        body: {'mobile': mobile, 'password': password});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Loginuser.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```